# Spring Boot Custom Validation Annotation Not Working as Expected

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, constraints

I'm currently working on a Spring Boot project and trying to implement a custom validation annotation that should be able to validate both individual field of an object and lists of objects. However, my current implementation doesn't work and throwing an exception.

> SampleValid class

```
@Target({ElementType.FIELD})
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Constraint(validatedBy = SampleValidator.class)
@Repeatable(SampleValid.List.class)
@Documented
public @interface SampleValid {

    String name() default "name";

    String message() default "";

    Class<?>[] groups() default {};

    Class<? extends Payload>[] payload() default {};

    @Target({ElementType.FIELD})
    @Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
    @Documented
    @interface List {
        SampleValid[] value();
    }
}
```

> SampleValidator class

```
public class SampleValidator implements ConstraintValidator<SampleValid, Object> {
        private String fieldName;
    
        public void initialize(SampleValid constraintAnnotation) {
            name = constraintAnnotation.name();
        }
    
        public boolean isValid(Object value, ConstraintValidatorContext context) {
            if (value == null) return true;
    
            try {
                String fieldValue = BeanUtils.getProperty(value, name);
    
                if (some validation goes here) {
                    context.disableDefaultConstraintViolation();
                    context.buildConstraintViolationWithTemplate(context.getDefaultConstraintMessageTemplate())
                            .addConstraintViolation();
                    return false;
                }
            } catch (Exception ex) {
                return false;
            }
    
            return true;
        }
    }
```

So when I am using this to validate a List it's throwing me an error, but this works with single objects,

```
@SampleValid
private List<SomeObject> someObjects;

@SampleValid
private SomeObject someObject; // this works fine
```

The error I am getting is,

> java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: Unknown property 'name' on class
> 'class java.util.ArrayList'

Could someone help me understand why my current implementation isn't working as expected? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue you're facing is because you are trying to access the "name" property of a List `List<SomeObject> someObjects` directly, but Lists don't have a "name" property.

Your custom validation annotation and validator are designed to validate properties on individual objects, not on a List itself.

If you want to validate properties of objects within the list, you should iterate through the list and validate each object individually.

I'm thinking about a modification like this of your `SampleValidator` class:

```java
public class SampleValidator implements ConstraintValidator<SampleValid, Object> {
    private String fieldName;

    public void initialize(SampleValid constraintAnnotation) {
        fieldName = constraintAnnotation.fieldName();
    }

    public boolean isValid(Object value, ConstraintValidatorContext context) {
        if (value == null) return true;

        if (value instanceof List) {
            List<?> list = (List<?>) value;
            for (Object item : list) {
                if (item != null) {
                    try {
                        String className = item.getClass().getSimpleName();
                        String fieldValue = BeanUtils.getProperty(item, fieldName);

                        // Perform your validation here
                        if (some validation goes here) {
                            context.disableDefaultConstraintViolation();
                            context.buildConstraintViolationWithTemplate(className + context.getDefaultConstraintMessageTemplate())
                                    .addConstraintViolation();
                            return false;
                        }
                    } catch (Exception ex) {
                        return false;
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        return true;
    }
}
```

in this case your validator will iterate through the list and validate each object's "name" property individually like this:

```java
@SampleValid
private List<SomeObject> someObjects;
```

Comment: Isn't this code do this automatically?

`@Target({ElementType.FIELD})
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Documented
@interface List {
    SampleValid[] value();
}`

Comment: The `@interface List` you've defined within your `SampleValid` annotation is for grouping multiple instances of `SampleValid` annotations on the same field. It allows you to apply multiple instances of `SampleValid` to a single field, and it doesn't automatically handle validation for a list of objects within the field.
In other words, the purpose of `@SampleValid.List` is to group multiple instances of `SampleValid` annotations together on a single field, but it doesn't automatically validate a list of objects within that field.

Comment: OK got it, I was confused with that thank you for the clear explanation and also for the answer. It's working fine now. Appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

I’m thinking why you need to validate list of object you can simply validate someObject then add it to list `javax.validation` mostly used for user input validation

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).